# IIS Idle Time-out triggers even though a SignalR connection is still present

Tags: iis, timeout, signalr

In my project, there is a process that can run for a very long time (> 20 min.). The progress is transmitted to interested clients as a percentage value using SignalR. Now I noticed that the server is rigorously terminated after 20 minutes (IIS default Idle Time-out), although a client is connected and actively receiving data via SignalR.

Could it be that communication via WebSockets is not monitored by the IIS routine that resets the timeout? Is there any way to work around the problem? Or have I implemented something wrong?

Comment: As you said, IIS default Idle timeout stop the connection. You can set its value larger or 0 to prevent timeout.